# Featured Image VS Post_thumbnail -- has_post_thumbnail lies?

Tags: post-thumbnails

OK, I got a custom post type with thumbnail enabled which adds the "featured images" panel to that post-type just fine, but in my template when I do

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
} else {
    echo 'none';
}
```

it just shows 'none' on each one even though I have a featured image set... I have `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails',array('post','custom_post_type'));` so it's supported by the theme but `has_post_thumbnail` always returns false what's going on here???

My template is :
archive-custom_post_type.php :

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'clients', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ));
if($loop){
?>
<ul>
<?php
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
            <?php 
                if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
                    echo get_post($post->ID)->post_excerpt;
                } else {
                    echo 'broken ::' . $post->ID;
                    echo get_post($post->ID)->post_excerpt;
                }

            ?>
            </a>
        </li>
<?php 
endwhile;
//wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Custom Post Type, do you `setup_postdata( $post )` in your custom Loop? If not, `has_post_thumbnail()` might not be defined/available?

EDIT:

Try adding:

```
setup_postdata( $post );
```

Right before:

```
$loop->the_post();
```

And then see if `has_post_thumbnail()` returns `true`?

Or, try passing the `$post->ID` to your call to `has_post_thumbnail()`?

```
has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID );
```

Comment: No I dont, I've updated the question with the full page

Comment: Then try adding `setup_postdata( $post );` (I *think*, right before `$loop->the_post()`)

Comment: nope, still returning 'none'

Comment: Is that both for using `setup_postdata()`, *and* for passing `$post->ID`to `has_post_thumbnail()`? **Another question**: are `the_permalink()` and `the_title_attribute()` working?

Comment: `the_post()` method calls `setup_postdata()` by itself, no need to add it.

Comment: `the_permalink` & `the_title_attribute` work... `has_post_thumbnail` and `post_excerpt` dont...

Comment: Can you post your custom post type registration function?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing $post->ID from the has_post_thumbnail(). Perhaps the $post object isn't referencing your current post.

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the top of your functions.php

```
if( ! function_exists( 'has_post_thumbnail' ) )
{
    function has_post_thumbnail( $pid )
    {       
        return get_post_meta( $pid, '_thumbnail_id', true );
    }
}
```

Comment: In the OPs case, `has_post_thumbnail` returned `false` incorrectly at all times. It didn't throw a `Call to undefined function` error. Please explain how your above code block would be of help to this issue.